# SQL/ORACLE--COUNT DISTINCT RETURNS ONLY "1" FOR ALL CONDITIONS

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
TAB1.TYPE,
TAB1.BILL_CYCLE,
COUNT(DISTINCT BILL_CYCLE)

FROM TAB1

WHERE TAB1.BILL_CYCLE BETWEEN '15-SEP-2022 4' AND '30-NOV-2022 4'
```

There should be 9 distinct BILL_CYCLE values with the date range provided in where clause, however I only get one.
you can see the result of the top query below:

```
BLI_Type                      BILL_CYCLE           COUNT(DISTICT BILL_CYCLE)

Total Due                  22-SEP-2022 04:00:00            1
Credits                    17-NOV-2022 05:00:00            1
Previous                   17-NOV-2022 05:00:00            1
```

RAW DATA SAMPLE:

| ID | ORG_NAME | BLI_TYPE | TOTAL | BILL_CYCLE |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | KK | TOTAL | -141 | 15-SEP-2022 4:00:00 |  |
| 1 | KK | CHARGES | 22 | 22-NOV-2022 4:00:00 |  |
| 1 | KK | CREDIT | 28 | 08-OCT-2022 5:00:00 |  |
| 1 | KK | CHARGES | -930 | 15-SEP-2022 4:00:00 |  |
| 2 | DD | PREVIOUS | 360 | 15-SEP-2022 4:00:00 |  |

Comment: This query is malformed and cannot run in Oracle. It will run in MySQL, though, with unpredictable results. If you use `COUNT()` on some columns only, you should have a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks, Would you be able to give me hint on how you group by count?

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result. It's not clear how the data looks like to me.

Comment: there is is link below the code under the description for result image, Stack over flow doesn't allow me to have the image automatically shown

Comment: Provide data sample as formatted text. This tool can help https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables. Is BILL_CYLCE field a text or date type?

Comment: here you go, hope it helps

Comment: That does not look like a raw data sample.

Comment: I just added the raw data as well.

Answer (score 2):

If date values are stored as dates (and not strings), you should fix that and compare dates to dates, not dates to strings:

```
SELECT
  TAB1.TYPE,
  TAB1.BILL_CYCLE,
  COUNT(DISTINCT BILL_CYCLE)
FROM TAB1
WHERE TAB1.BILL_CYCLE BETWEEN to_date('15.09.2022 04:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                          AND to_date('30.11.2022 04:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:Ss')
GROUP BY tab1.type, tab1.bill_cycle;
```

Apart from that, it seems that every *timestamp* is unique so that's why you're getting `1` as a result. Perhaps you wanted to count rows truncated to e.g. day - then you'd

```
select type, trunc(bill_cycle), count(distinct trunc(bill_cycle))
from tab1
WHERE TAB1.BILL_CYCLE BETWEEN to_date('15.09.2022 04:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
                          AND to_date('30.11.2022 04:00:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:Mi:Ss')
group by type, trunc(bill_cycle);
```

You could've done that not to *day* but to an *hour*; no problem, just include that into the query.

Comment: The query still returns one for all counts

The dates aren't unique, there multiple of the same bill_cycle dates,

Comment: So, what result do you expect - based on sample data you posted in question (and why)?

Comment: the link you the same question sloved it, thank you

Comment: So, you got result you wanted? If so, great! You're welcome.